# Compare datatable and return rows with changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to compare two datatable and return only rows which has changes. In the below code I am cloning dt2 into dt3 but it doesn't pick the rows with changes instead it puts everything in there. Pls suggest some options.

Even if a single cell value is modified then I need to pick that row. Both datatable with have same set of rows and column each time I compare.

```
 Table 1              Table 2

ID   Name             ID     Name

1    Mark             1      Mark

2    Spencer          2      Spencer     

3    Ryan             3      George
```

**Table 3 Expected Result:**

```
ID     Name

3      George
```

**CODE:**

```
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
// It will compare the 2nd table with the 1st table
var contacts = dt2.AsEnumerable().Except(dt1.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default); 
dt3 = dt2.Clone();
foreach (DataRow rows in contacts)
 {
    dt3.ImportRow(rows);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need two tables for this purpose. Simply calling `GetChanges()` on the second `DataTable` will get you the last row that has changed. Make sure you haven't (directly or indirectly) called `AcceptChanges()` on the `DataTable`, otherwise `GetChanges()` won't return anything.

`DataRow` exposes a property named `RowState` that is set to `Modified` when one or more columns of it get changed. `AcceptChanges()` and `RejectChanges()` reset this flag back to `Unmodified`.

You can even get the original value (Ryan in your case) and current value (George in your case) of a column by calling the indexer of `DataRow` with the second parameter (`RowVersion`) set to `Original` and `Current` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dt1.Select()
    .Join(dt2.Select(), x => x["Id"], y => y["Id"], (x, y) => new { x, y })
    .Where(z => z.x["Name"] != z.y["Name"])
    .Select(z => z.y);
```

Here `dt1` is `Table 1` and `dt2` is `Table 2`.

It tries to join tables by `Id`, and then filters out records with same `Name`.